# UWP certificate issue on hosted agents

Tags: tfs, uwp, devops, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to run UWP build using Team Foundation Server and App Center and it gives me this error.

```
 ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3090,5): Error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: AppCenterTest.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_480BF88F6934FA8C
```

I tried creating a private agent for Team Foundation Server which fixed the issue for Team Foundation Server only since the certificate is installed on my private agent. But for App Center by default is running a hosted agent.

How to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a custom certificate? Which source control are you using TFVC or GIT? Moreover did the `AppCenterTest.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx` key you have added in source control?

Comment: I'm using git. and I include AppCenterTest.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx.

Comment: I create the certificate in Package.appxmanifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Creating a test certificate in Package.appxmanifest > Packaging > Choose Certificate. I create the certificate in my UWP project Properties > Signing > Choose a strong name key file: > New. This steps resolved my issue.

Comment: My scenario: The default certificate doesn't work (UWP project creation). So I created a test certificate in Package.appxmanifest > Packaging > Choose Certificate, then UWP project Properties > Signing > Choose a strong name key file: > Browse and select my created test certificate. Note* This is the fail step.

Comment: Glad to here the issue fixed,  seems the issue still related to your certificate file. Thanks for the sharing, once you could, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below  statement:

> **Select the right type of build agent**
>
> Choose the type of build agent that you want VSTS to use when it
>   executes the build process. A hosted build agent is deployed with the
>   most common tools and sdks, and it will work for most scenarios, see
>   the Software on the hosted build server article. However, you can
>   create a custom build agent if you need more control over the build
>   steps. You can use the following table to help you make that decision.

[image]

*Note: If you plan to target the Windows Anniversary Update SDK (Build 14393) you will need to set up your custom build agent, since the hosted build pool only supports SDK 10586 and 10240. More information to choose a UWP version*

Besides, if you use a **Git** repository, add the certificate file of your project to the repository so that the build agent can sign the appx package. If you don’t do this, the Git repository will ignore the certificate file. To add the certificate file to your repository, right-click the certificate file in Solution Explorer, and then in the shortcut menu, choose the Add Ignored File to Source Control command.

[image]

More details please refer this tutorial: [Set up automated builds for your UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps)